# Radio button not toggling in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, radio-button, radio-group

Hi I have a set of radio options and by default first option has class "currently-selected" to it.

Now, when I click other options, I need to remove the "currently-selected" class from all other radio options and add it the currently selected option.

This is the JS that I am using and works fine on all browsers except IE. On IE all other options have "currently-selected" and not being toggled.

Here is the structure.

```
<div id="edit-donation-amount"><div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-25" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-25" name="donation_amount" value="25" checked="checked" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-25" class="option">$25</label>
      </div>
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-50" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-50" name="donation_amount" value="50" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-50" class="option">$50</label>
      </div>
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount currently-selected">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-100" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-100" name="donation_amount" value="100" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-100" class="option">$100</label>
      </div>
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-500" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-500" name="donation_amount" value="500" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-500" class="option">$500</label>
      </div>
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-1000" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-1000" name="donation_amount" value="1000" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-1000" class="option">$1000</label>
      </div>
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-radio form-item-donation-amount js-form-item-donation-amount">
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-donation-amount-other" type="radio" id="edit-donation-amount-other" name="donation_amount" value="other" class="form-radio">

        <label for="edit-donation-amount-other" class="option">Other</label>
      </div>
</div>

var $radioButtons = $('#edit-donation-amount input[type="radio"]');
            $radioButtons.click(function() {
                $radioButtons.each(function() {
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('currently-selected', this.checked);
                });
            });
```

IE issue in image below:
[image: donation2]

Any leads as to why it fails on IE will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting a `class` that determines the state of your radio button? That take away the normal functionality of your element. If you need different styling, why not just style it differently and leave the functionality alone?  Also, what's you CSS so we can better determine what's really going on?

Comment: Hi @computercarguy have added my structure.

Comment: better structure and no need for JavaScript

Comment: You probably want to use change and not click. You probably also want to trigger the event so the code runs to properly set the class when the page loads.